# Drone keeps rising (in simulation) after takeoff

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently using the tum_simulator + ROS + gazebo to run a simulation for the Parrot A.R. drone 2.0.

When I publish the takeoff message ( `rostopic pub -1 /ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/Empty` )  the drone rises ( in the gazebo simulation)
but doesn't stop. I can't make it stop even by pressing the "lower z-velocity" (`rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}`')  command. (These commands have been taken from official tum_simulator ROS wiki page [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator) )
( And yes, I am keeping the teleoperation terminal active so I can see my commands work
but the drone keeps rising )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281462/drone-keeps-rising-(in-simulation)-after-takeoff./) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently, [others](https://answers.ros.org/question/269932/drone-doesnt-stop-taking-off/#269988) have had this problem too and the solution was to install some `hector` packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-gazebo
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-sensors-gazebo
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-xacro-tools
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-03**:
If this solved your problem, please click on the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-03**:
Thanks ! I installed the first two and it works :D